# Arduino-cli daemon purpose

Tags: arduino, command-line-interface, daemon

Can anyone explain me how the arduino-cli daemon is working and what this is doing? I cant find any good documentation on the web...

When I start the daemon it only tells me, it started listening to some port.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what to explain beyond the manual.

`arduino-cli daemon` starts a gRPC server.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC

It provides a language agnostic interface to other programs so they can use the features of the Arduino CLI.

So like you sit in front of the computer and enter commands into the CLI, a client software would connect to the gRPC server and invoke whatever commands it needs.

Read this

https://blog.arduino.cc/2020/07/06/the-three-pillars-of-the-arduino-cli/

Comment: it can run as daemon to provided services for an IDE